# Show JSON Data in a Table using foreach loop

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am making a table which will fetch data from API. I am able to fetch the first value, How can i use foreach with my code? I am not able to do so.

My Table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Steam URL</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $name;?></th>
        <th><?php echo $steam;?></th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And My PHP Code:

```
$name = $json->submissions[0]->data->name;
$steam = $json->submissions[0]->data->steam;
```

It's showing first value correct but not able to get the second entry.

Comment: Does second entry exists?

Comment: Yes, It does. API Used: https://formkeep.com/api/v1/forms/125ae3ee8c6a/submissions.json

Comment: This URL ask for Username and password!

Comment: I don't see a `foreach()` in your code

Comment: Could you consider undeleting https://stackoverflow.com/q/54012997/6309? This was a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one if it works!

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Steam URL</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($json->submissions as $key => $submission): ?>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $submission->data->name;?></th>
            <th><?php echo $submission->data->steam;?></th>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property 'data' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\uig\entries.php on line 99

Comment: It's working now, BTW please close <table> tag. Ty :D