# How to find diff in a specific file on git using web browser

Tags: git, github

I know for Git Bash, you can use this command:**git diff [--options]   [--] [...]** but I want to know if there is any way to find difference between a specific file using browser.

Like we can find changes in commits, but that includes all files (https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/c3a414e..faf7c6)

I just want to find changes to one specific file.

Comment: I haven't seen that option in the website. I might say that you cannot perform what you mentioned because you can only compare by branches, tags, commits, forks, and also time "[doc](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/)". So in order to compare and just get one file you would need to compare by the file you want to see the changes. You might try using the Git Bash client, or any other client to get what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at least (through the browser) see commits which actually involved a given file.
For that, you need to access the ["History" page of said fil](https://help.github.com/articles/differences-between-commit-views/)e:

https://github.com/github/linguist/commits/master/lib/linguist/heuristics.rb

But that does not give you any diff between two commits.

Another workaround is at least to get to the blame view of that file.

https://github.com/github/linguist/blame/master/lib/linguist/heuristics.rb

For any diff shown here, you can [click and see the previous revision information for that line, including who committed the change and when](https://blog.github.com/2017-01-18-navigate-file-history-faster-with-improved-blame-view/).

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3477155/21945511/a5145ddc-d9a9-11e6-9723-85f8c498139b.gif]